# Date conversion gives NA in some months

Tags: r

I want to parse some Apache-Logfiles in R, but date conversion does not work in some months. Example:

```
> as.Date(c("11/Jan/2012", "11/Mar/2012", "11/Apr/2012", "11/May/2012"), "%d/%b/%Y")
[1] "2012-01-11" NA          
[3] "2012-04-11" NA
```

Why does Jan and Apr work and Mar and May not?

Kind regards,
Arne

Comment: This might be a locale issue. What is the result of `Sys.getlocale()` ?

Comment: @Andrie: This could be the answer. Locales are all _German_Germany.1252_. I'll change the locale and will try again.

Comment: Works now! Setting _LC_TIME_ to _ENGLISH_US_ did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "ENGLISH_US")`